# Set recipient email address with wetransfer.com

Tags: url, wetransfer

Is it possible to autofill the recipient’s address via a URL link in wetransfer.com?

I would like to be able to give a link to send us files, where the email address we want it sent to is filled in already.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the "to" address to the URL like so:

```
https://wetransfer.com/?to=test@example.com
```

Comment: So simple I didn't even think of trying it.

Comment: Side note: the parameter for the message body is `msg`

Comment: Is it documented anywhere? It would give me a huge convenience to know if there is a parameter to indicate a file to attach!

Comment: Does a parameter `from` exists ? I cannot find any documentation. Thanks !

Comment: @apiaget I can't see a parameter for `from` and I can't find any doco, these parameters were found by poking through their code.

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can add multiple mail.

```
https://www.wetransfer.com/?to=alpha@example.com%20beta@example.com
```

And add your bookmarks for continuous use.

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to preset a message as well:

```
https://wetransfer.com/?to=alpha@example.com&msg=my%20message
```